# Unknown error code during application install: "-25"

Tags: android, failed-installation

I uploaded an app in Google play store. But users are complaining that they are unable to download app due to unkown error "25"

I have searched for information through Google, but I could not find anything concrete.

After download the app, this message appears when you are installing: Unknown error code during application install: "25"

Any idea on how to rectify this error?

Comment: You are getting this error on particular device or on all android devices?

Comment: I also updated an app and 3 users (out of 4500 active installs) left reviews saying they get unknown error -24 (once) and unknown error 504 (twice) when trying to install the update. Maybe it's because I pushed out several small updates in a 24-hour period and some phones got 'confused'? or maybe it's somehow something to do with my recent move to command-line building? Unfortunately the Play Store account is not really mine and doesn't give me options to reply to reviews, so I'm hoping to find a general solution to post in the app's "what's new" text and hope the affected people see it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to app manager > play store > clear data

[image]

Comment: And that does what? As in: How does that link to the question?

Comment: This Error -25 come when downloading any app. Clear data and reinstall solve in my case

Comment: But it's not the OP who downloads the app... ;)

Comment: So I guess this answer is really saying "tell the person who complained to try clearing data on Play Store"?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the fix is the same as that of Unknown error code during application install: “-24”.

. First root your Android device using instructions available on forums like XDA or Cyanogenmod

2. Install a file manager that can access Android Data files in the root directory or internal phone memory
3. Open the file manager app and navigate to the root folder

Go to "/data/data/" and search for your application package which should be in the format com.abc.xyz (example: com.process.google.gapps)
If you are unsure of the package name just Google your app and find the details. Delete the entire package folder

4. Install the app from Google Play Store

Source with detail steps: [How to Fix Android Unknown error code 24](http://valuestuffz.blogspot.com/2015/04/How-to-Fix-Unkown-Error-code-24-play-store.html)

Comment: I'm sorry but if someone complains about your app on the App Store, it probably wouldn't be considered an acceptable solution to tell them to root their device, unless the app in question is something that naturally attracts a lot of people who root their devices anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Error code: -25 
INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE
The new package has an older version code than the currently installed package.

That means users have installed another version of your app, that existing version has an older version that the one they are trying to install.

To solve your problem you need to upload your app to PlayStore with a newer (higher) version.